# Перестали записываться трансляции с youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

Добрый день.

Ранее получал ссылку следующим способом:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo -g URL
```

И записывал например 20 секунд:

```
ffmpeg -i NEW_URL -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -t 00:00:20 OUTPUT_FILE
```

Сейчас не работает, ошибки не сыпятся.

[Пример](https://www.youtube.com/embed/t2q89jtvEq8) трансляции которую пытаюсь записать.

На сервере ничего не менялось.

Есть у кого опыт записи кусков видео с Youtube, поделитесь опытом?

Comment: Поставить свежую версию youtube-dl пробовали?

Comment: Как ни странно, не пробывал ) youtube-dl отдает ссылку, почему то сомнений в ее валидности не возникало, но зато всячески извращался над ffmpeg.

Огромное вам спасибо за совет )) действительно, после обновления все заработало